# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post, networkonmainthread

I'm building an application and am getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException *INSIDE* an AsyncTask

Call:

```
new POST(this).execute("");
```

asyncTask:

```
public class POST extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, HttpResponse>{
private MainActivity form;
public POST(MainActivity form){
    this.form = form;
}


@Override
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://diarwe.com:8080/account/login");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",((EditText)form.findViewById(R.id.in_email)).getText().toString()));
    //add more...
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httppost);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("BackgroundError", e.toString());
}
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
try {
    Gson gSon = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
    gSon.fromJson(IOUtils.toString(result.getEntity().getContent()), LogonInfo.class).fill(form);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("BackgroundError", e.toString());
}
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
BackgroundError | android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

I'm very confused why this exception is thrown in the do in the doInBackground of an AsyncTask, any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the `JSON` code into `doInBackground()`:

```
@Override
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
    ...
    Your current HttpPost code...
    ...
    Gson gSon = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
    gSon.fromJson(IOUtils.toString(result.getEntity().getContent()), LogonInfo.class).fill(form);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Everything in `AsyncTask` is on the main UI Thread except for `doInBackground()`. The general idea is to support common use-cases such as the following: Setup your `ProgressBar` in `onPreExecute()`, update your `ProgressBar` in `onProgressUpdate()`, and finally dismiss your `ProgressBar` in `onPostExecute()`. All of those functions are UI Thread safe while `doInBackground()` can safely take as much time as it needs.

Answer (score 2):

`result.getEntity().getContent()` opens a stream that reads from the network, so the network communication IS in the main thread. Move the JSON parsing to `doInBackground()` and do only the UI tasks in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Just for future reference, `onPostExicute` is on the main thread?

Comment: that is correct. `onPreExecute()` too. Everything you need to know can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs since your are inheriting the  `MainActivity` into your `AsyncTask`, try to reomve this part of code:

```
private MainActivity form;
public POST(MainActivity form){
    this.form = form;
}
```

Since you dont need it, and if you want to pass any arguments to the `AsyncTask` you can pass it through the `doInBackGround()` method immediatliy.

Also to call your `AsyncTask` use the following `new POST().execute();`

Also you don't need to call `super.onPostExecute(result);` into your `onPostExecute()` method.

I hope this help.